# Extract pattern using Regex in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I want to extract the below pattern from the dataframe:

```
Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
```

I have written the below code to extract it:

```
d4=df.str.extractall(r'((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z][?:]*)((?:\d{1,2}(?:th|st|nd|rd)[,?:])\d{4})')
```

Unfortunately, it is not able to extract anything.

Comment: Expected result!

Comment: Mar 20th, 2009,Mar 21st, 2009,Mar 22nd, 2009

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your date format would only be: MMM DDst/nd/rd/th, YYYY, thus Mar 01st, 2009 instead of Mar 1st, 2009. The following regex should work well.
`\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (?:[0-3][1]st|[0-2][2]nd|[0-2][3]rd|[1-3][0]th|[0-2][4-9]th), \d{4}`

[Python Regex Demo](http://rextester.com/PLAWJ75767)

Answer (score 1):

I saw multiple problems/doubts with your pattern, so I just rewrote it from the start as this:

```
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d{1,2}(?:th|st|nd|rd),\s+\d{4}
```

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
(?:Jan|Feb|...|Dec)    match, but do not capture, the abbreviated month name
\s+                    one or more spaces
\d{1,2}                day as one or two digits
(?:th|st|nd|rd)        match, but do not capture, day quantifier
\s+                    one or more spaces
\d{4}                  match a four digit year
```

Full code:

```
my_str = 'Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009'

match = re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d{1,2}(?:th|st|nd|rd),\s+\d{4}', my_str)

for item in match:
    print(item)
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

It needs some whitespaces.

`((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s+((?:\d{1,2}(?:th|st|nd|rd)[,?:])\s+\d{4})`

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           Jan
        |  Feb
        |  Mar
        |  Apr
        |  May
        |  Jun
        |  Jul
        |  Aug
        |  Sep
        |  Oct
        |  Nov
        |  Dec
      )
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s+ 
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?:
           \d{1,2} 
           (?: th | st | nd | rd )
           [,?:] 
      )
      \s+ 
      \d{4} 
 )                             # (2 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split`.

**Regex**: [`;\s`](https://regex101.com/r/cvrwYQ/2)

Details:

- `\s` Matches any whitespace character

**Python code**:

```
def Split(text):
        return re.split(r';\s', text)

print(Split("Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009"))
```

Output:

```
['Mar 20th, 2009', 'Mar 21st, 2009', 'Mar 22nd, 2009;']
```

[Code demo](http://rextester.com/UGIKD36785)